# Apache Basic Auth not working in .htaccess or Directory blocks; works fine in Location blocks

Tags: .htaccess, authentication, basic-authentication, apache2.4

OK, running Apache 2.4.7 on Ubuntu 14.04, freshly installed.

If I add the following to the .conf file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`, then basic auth works fine:

```
<Location /test>
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName ".htaccess Basic Auth Test"
  AuthUserFile "/var/www/passwords/test"
  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

**However**, if I just have the following in a `.htaccess` file in the relevant directory:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName ".htaccess Basic Auth Test"
AuthUserFile "/var/www/passwords/test"
Require valid-user
```

The auth seems to be ignored; no prompt, and pages served as if they're not there. Same happens with a Directory block:

```
<Directory /var/www/default/test>
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName ".htaccess Basic Auth Test"
  AuthUserFile "/var/www/passwords/test"
  Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

So, I checked if the `.htaccess` files were actually being read, and they are; adding

```
Options -Indexes
```

to the `.htaccess` file does remove the index listing on the directory.

I turned on debugging but that wasn't particularly useful:

```
[Tue Apr 21 13:04:14.082275 2015] [authz_core:debug] [pid 8914] mod_authz_core.c(721): [client 144.32.48.10:64109] AH01625: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted (directive limited to other methods)
[Tue Apr 21 13:04:14.082538 2015] [authz_core:debug] [pid 8914] mod_authz_core.c(721): [client 144.32.48.10:64109] AH01625: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted (directive limited to other methods)
```

Grep'ing in `/etc/apache2` shows nothing that would restrict this; no other `Auth` statements, `AllowOverride All` in the right places (as shown by the Options test; and they say `All`, not anything else that might restrict the overrides).

I feel like I must be missing something obvious. Here's the modules loaded:

```
root@linode:/etc/apache2# apachectl -M
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 php5_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
 substitute_module (shared)
 xml2enc_module (shared)
```

Comment: Just a try. Without `"`: `AuthUserFile /var/www/passwords/test` because I never use them, and that can eventually be a problem with absolute path...

Comment: @Croises Alas, no; I think I added them in case it changed anything!

Comment: Did you try to change the `AuthName ".htaccess Basic Auth Test"` for each test ? Because if you ask for the same `AuthName` for 2 or more directories, the browser ask just the first time...

Comment: @Croises Just tried a different name, no change, it's still ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I knew I'd done something interesting. My server was being tested out for proxying, so a site advised that I add this to `apache2.conf:`

```
<Location />
   <Limit CONNECT>
     Require all denied
   </Limit>
</Location>
```

Removed that (on a whim - didn't look like it'd change it) and basic auth works again!

To protect the site, I moved the block to the default (IP address only) virtualhost, so the others will function fine.

Answer (score -2):

Another solution is to install the [WP htaccess Control plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-htaccess-control/)
and add this line in *Custom htaccess*:

```
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
```

[image: Screenshot of settings]