# Acces Control only works inside <Location> directive, Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)

Tags: apache2.4

There's a server with several instances of Apache running. One instance needs access from anywhere, but only for authorized users. Instance is started up by a systemctl script with the -f option pointing to a config file in /opt/.

Config includes directives from another file in the same folder under /opt/. The relevant part of the included directives looks like the following at the present moment:

"

```
[...]

  <Location "/subfolder">
      <RequireAll>
        Require all granted
        Require valid-user
      </RequireAll>
   LimitRequestBody <someNumber>
  </Location>

[...]

  DavLockDB /somepath/webdav/DavLock

  Alias /subfolder /mainfolder/subfolder
  <Directory /mainfolder/subfolder>
      Dav on
      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Restricted Files"
      AuthUserFile /somepath/webdav/.htpasswd
      <RequireAll>
        Require all granted
        Require valid-user
      </RequireAll>
      AllowOverride All
      SSLRequireSSL
      Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
  </Directory>

[...]
```

"

This works so far, it only permits access to folder if you enter your username and password.

Problem is, if I comment out the `<Location` directive to comply with security recommendations, then access is flat-out denied. There is no way to enter a username and a password, and if I supply them on the command line, they are ignored, while they previously worked with the `<Location` block intact.

The `<RequireAll>` block inside the `<Directory>` directive is completely ineffectual. In fact, if I comment it out there, it changes nothing whatsoever in the behaviour of the httpd instance. It works only when it is placed inside the `<Location` block. The rest of the `<Directory>` block on the other hand seems to be working.

Does someone have any tips as to what I may be missing here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

H/T to [Apache Basic Auth not working in .htaccess or Directory blocks; works fine in Location blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29772246/apache-basic-auth-not-working-in-htaccess-or-directory-blocks-works-fine-in-lo?rq=1)

The problem was that the configuration file the Apache instance is started up with included one of the system-wide configs in `/etc/` with a default location block inside, similar to the following:

```
<Location />
  Require all denied
  [...]
</Location>
```

When I commented out the line `Require all denied` from here, the access control directives in the `<Directory>` block started to work as expected.

The explanation of the above is that, unlike "normal" `<Location>` directives, which "operate completely outside the filesystem", `<Location />` refers to the entire server (see the Apache documentation: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#location ), so it means pretty much the same as `<Directory />` (at least when it comes to its scope), except that it can only be overridden by another `<Location>` directive.